# NativeScript Publishing with SideKick iOS error (privacy policy URL)

Tags: nativescript, sidekick

Sidekick publishing worked a few days ago for me but now I am getting this SideKick error message below when I try to publish to the apple store.  Not sure how to resolve this issue.

An error has occurred while uploading the package
Error: Publishing failed. 
[31m [!] The request could not be completed because: You must provide a Privacy Policy URL. You must provide a Privacy Policy URL.[0m Publishing failed.

Comment: Is there any notifications in the apple dev store, i had similar issue i had to use xcode to push up to store and it provided a detailed message of what i was missing.

Comment: I am using a windows pc so I am not able to push with xcode.  When I log into appstoreconnect.apple.com I do not get any notifications about missing privacy policy info.